# Android - selecting tile in gameboard by touch?

Tags: android, selection

i am developing checkers application for Android. I have drawn on Canvas gameboard and tiles for each side, also I have made selection of tiles by D-Pad. But what about, Android phone doesn't have D-Pad? There must be a way how to do that in touch (I touch a tile - it is selected now). Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

image of my Gameboard can be found here - http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/7814/checkers.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store tile locations in a 2d Array. On the finger down event, check the event location against each tile. When you find the tile that was poked, select it.

Answer (score 1):

Another (easier?) alternative is to use Android's standard Button/ImageButton. You can customize its border and content, if you don't want the default border to show up.

The standard Buttons works with both touch and D-pad; so you can cut the amount of coding you need to make tiles that behave properly under both situations.